# Unable to update Flashplayer

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, flash-player

I've had this issue awhile now, and I don't know how to fix it. I have a Windows 7 64x bit system and use Admin rights when I try to install the Flash player but it says that I don't have the rights to do that.

System Windows 7 64x German

[image]

I tried to clear the cache and ran the de-installer program from Abobe.

Comment: go to the syswow64 folder, select the flash exe, make a rightclick, go to security and give admins full control of the file.

Comment: didn't worked but i found a solution i Enabled the Built-in Elevated Administrator and tried there to install it and it worked which is odd but fine to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Distribution download rather than the streaming version & run as Admin

It moves around, current link is at  http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html

Comment: sorry but it didn't worked for me

[the Error Message from the MSI installer](http://s1.bild.me/bilder/030315/9933151new.png)

[the Error Message from the EXE installer](http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=4947659new2.jpg)